# How to add a custom "Implement Interface" option to light-bulb icon in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-code, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to add a custom version of "Implement Interface" to the light-bulb icon in Visual Studio Code (for C# projects) to assist with the development of projects that use a framework.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a Roslyn CodeFix that you distribute with your framework via a nuget package, possibly looking at the [Roslyn implementation](http://source.roslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features/R/46fa47262d9e65e0.html) for how to get started.

Comment: Thanks; I had to download the '.NET Compiler Platform SDK' extension for Visual Studio to get the project template and SDK to compile the Roslyn plugin which seems to work fine in VS; but I cannot seem to get VS:Code to load the plugin. I have added the analyzer reference to the project file, but I guess VS:Code doesn't care about project files... any thoughts?

Comment: I've also tried bundling the plugin in a local nuget package; and again VS is detecting this fine; but VS:Code doesn't seem to be :(

Comment: Right now, CodeFixes being loaded from NuGet aren't supported in Visual Studio Code. The templates Kevin pointed you to are for main Visual Studio only.